# How can we tackle with the situation where the result of FROM-Subquery is needed in WHERE-Clause?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Consider the following schema:

```
create table UserInterests
(UserName varchar(20),
InterestID int
primary key (UserName, InterestID)
 )
```

Now, if I want to find the most common interest of users (the interest with largest number of users), how would I do that.

My attempt is as follows:

```
select InterestID, CountInterest
from (select InterestID, count (*) as CountInterest
        from UserInterests
        group by InterestID) as x
where x.CountInterest = (select max (CountInterest)
                            from x)
```

But upon execution it says, *x* is an invalid object. So how should I handle such situations?

Comment: Because `x` isn't an object; it's subquery. What you want is a CTE, not a subquery.

Comment: Though, why not use a `TOP (1) WITH TIES`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
;with cte
as (
    select InterestID, count (*) as CountInterest
    from UserInterests
    group by InterestID
    )
select top(1) InterestID, countInterest
from cte
order by countInterest desc
```